# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, invoke, mobile-application, virtual-functions

have some issue when i run this code on android studio app got crash.

package com.example.myapplication;

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstScreen extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TextView textView =  findViewById(R.id.newScreen);
        String value ;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        value=intent.getStringExtra("Sending");
        textView.setText(value);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESFZD.png)

Comment: You called findViewById before setting content Google serach findViewById returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView textView =  findViewById(R.id.newScreen);` should be after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_screen);`

Comment: Thanks for the help ,Now its working u were right